# Vue.js how can i sum values i print

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I work on a commercial site and when the customer orders a product, I do the following:
Printing the price of the product first for example $ 60
Then if the customer chooses the fast shipping service, I print the value of the express shipping service, for example, $20.
How do I addition and print numbers in Total?

```
<ul>
    <li>Price : {{product.product_price}} Doller</li>
    <li v-if="orderData.fastDelivry">Fast delivry : {{delevryValue}} Doller</li>
    <li>Total : </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Take a look at [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Comment: Use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to perform the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      product: {
        name: 'prod 1',
        product_price: 15
      },
      orderData: {
        fastDelivry: false
      },
      delevryValue: 5
    }
  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      return (this.orderData.fastDelivry ? this.product.product_price + this.delevryValue :  this.product.product_price)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setDelivery() {
      this.orderData.fastDelivry = !this.orderData.fastDelivry
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<ul>
    <li>Price : {{product.product_price}} Doller</li>
    <input type="checkbox" @click="setDelivery" /> fast delivery 
    <li v-if="orderData.fastDelivry">Fast delivry : {{delevryValue}} Doller</li>
    <li>Total : {{ total }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```